# how do you make img 100% of its parents height

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am working on a page with a lot of text on it, and I want to include an image. The problem is that the img is taller than the paragraph. Does anyone know how I can make the img 100% of its container?

```css
.container {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ullamcorper interdum risus eget ultrices. Morbi placerat ante nec accumsan tempus. Donec aliquam ex lectus, quis dignissim lacus tempor sit
    amet. Proin varius dui sit amet enim semper, sit amet pharetra metus convallis. Cras at velit mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi dignissim elit turpis, vel pretium leo rhoncus ac. Nunc
    egestas arcu non nisi volutpat sagittis. Phasellus porttitor sollicitudin tellus, vel egestas nibh ultrices nec.
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add a plnkr with your existing code?

Comment: @StephenR.Smith please do not suggest only adding a link to code. All relevant code should be included *in the question itself*

Comment: @Brandon your problem is the float you have put on the image

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `float` takes the image otu of the standard flow, so you need to implement [Clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/):

**1. Create the clearfix class in CSS:**

Add the following CSS (Note: this it works for IE8 and higher. If you need to support older browsers, check the link above).

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

**2. Apply the clearfix to your HTML:**

Add the clearfix class to the div that holds your image i.e. `<p class="container clearfix">`

**Working Demo**:

***Note:*** I have your container width to 100% so that you can see the effect - otherwise in the small CodeSnippet window, the text was not short enough to cause the issue you describe.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}

img {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="container clearfix">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ullamcorper interdum risus eget ultrices. Morbi placerat ante nec accumsan tempus. Donec aliquam ex lectus, quis dignissim lacus tempor sit
    amet. Proin varius dui sit amet enim semper, sit amet pharetra metus convallis. Cras at velit mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi dignissim elit turpis, vel pretium leo rhoncus ac. Nunc
    egestas arcu non nisi volutpat sagittis. Phasellus porttitor sollicitudin tellus, vel egestas nibh ultrices nec.
  </p>
</body>
```